# angular-cli error using angular 4 & angular2-materialize --HarmonyImportDependency

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-cli

cli. It was working fine untill I decided to install angular2-materialize with it had to install dependencies. After that compliation broke and i keept getting the error shown in the error. I am trying to figure out when angular-cli builds the project where the reference is so I can remove it. [image]

Please let me know how to take care of this error. 
Thanks

Comment: Given that the error is coming from crypto.js, im assuming that you have cryptojs as a dependency in your package.json. Have you tried updating that to the latest release?

Comment: i did run npm update command

Comment: try running `npm install cryptojs@latest --save` where cryptojs is whatever the name of the dependency is (Im unsure if its cryptojs or crypto-js, just make sure the name matches whats installed in your package.json file)